# create SOAP header using PHP

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, soap-client

I'm new to `SOAP` and I can't figure how to create a `SOAP header` using the following template:

I am programming in PHP using SoapClient.

```
 <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Username xmlns="http://something.com/WebServices/SMSPush">User</Username>
    <Password xmlns="http://something.com/WebServices/SMSPush">Pass</Password>
    <To SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">http://wsmcg002.something.sys:8004/SmsPushService.svc</To>
    <Action SOAP-ENV:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">SendMultipleTextMessage</Action>
</SOAP-ENV:Header>
```

Answer (score 2):

You set the SOAP header using [SoapHeader](http://php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php) class

```
<?php
$client = new SoapClient(...);

$headers = array();
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://something.com/WebServices/SMSPush', 'Username', 'Usser');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://something.com/WebServices/SMSPush', 'Password', 'Pass');
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none', 'To', 'http://wsmcg002.something.sys:8004/SmsPushService.svc', true);
$headers[] = new SoapHeader('http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none', 'Action', 'SendMultipleTextMessage', true);
$client->__setSoapHeaders($headers);
```